# Spring Data JPA @Query provides java: <identifier> expected

Tags: jpa

I tried to use @Query as follows

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM PERSON", nativeQuery = true)
```

but I'm getting

```
java: <identifier> expected
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to bind the `@Query` annotation to a method.

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM PERSON", nativeQuery = true)
void deleteAllPersons();
```